# Is UIViewController's beginAppearanceTransition:animated: method available in iOS5

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I need to use `beginAppearanceTransition:animated:` in a `UIViewController` subclass that implements controller containment with custom animation transitions. I need to support iOS5 as a minimum.

The Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/beginAppearanceTransition%3aanimated%3a) say the method is:

> Available in iOS 6.0 and later

Yet UIViewController.h has the method tagged with:

> __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0)

I'm hoping the docs are just wrong. Can anyone give me a definitive answer on whether I'm allowed to call this in iOS5?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `IPHONE_5_0` stands for the iPhone 5, which is iOS 6, although I could be wrong.

Comment: Other methods are tagged with NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0), which is defined as #define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios) - so I'm thinking it means iOS 5.0 rather than "iPhone 5".

Comment: Well, maybe it means iOS, but I think you should trust apples docs here or test on an iOS device, because apples' docs are most likely correct

Comment: Why not try it in the simulator with the OS set to 5.1?  If it isn't available your app will crash with an error.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes APIs appear in iOS non-publicly before you're allowed to call them, which can lead to app-store rejection. Just because it doesn't crash in iOS 5 doesn't mean you're allowed to call it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I filed a bug report with Apple about this discrepancy and got the response that the methods are available in iOS 5.0.  The headers are right and the documentation is wrong.  I've filed another report to ask for the documentation to be updated...

The methods were added to the public headers in the iOS 6 SDK, but are available and can be used on devices running iOS 5.0.

**Update (28-Aug-2013)**

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has been updated to show that `beginAppearanceTransition:animated:` and `endAppearanceTransition` are available on iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience when in doubt, the headers are more accurate. the docs are generated / written using the headers. So I assume at this point that iOS 5 is supported.

**Now I tested it on the simulator.** Once for 5.0 and once for iOS 6.1 and the moths are called on both versions whenever you push or pop a vc.

Comment: ??? question: is it available, answer: yes it is. :) I don't see where I went wrong here -- read the comments

Comment: Perhaps you can expand then? I'd have posted that as a comment myself. An explanation, examples, links to evidence, etc.

Comment: added some more context to it.... if it feels to short still, ill happily delete it as I don't know what else to say :D -- but it was an answer ;)

Comment: A lot better! Now it won't show up in the Low Quality review queue anymore.

Comment: ah thats it! sorry for that. Ill try to formulate better answers from now - thanks :)