# Relaying appearance method calls in custom container view controller properly

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I'm following [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) to build my own custom container view controller. It seems to work just fine out of the box, except for one irritating problem.

How exactly do I specify at which time my child view controller will receive `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` calls (and their `disappear` counterparts)?

Let's say I have a fancy animation of a child sliding into the parent or something like that. Quite naturally, I'd like `viewWillAppear:YES` to be called at the beginning of the animation and `viewDidAppear:YES` at the end. However, by default both `viewWillAppear:NO` and `viewDidAppear:NO` are called at the same time upon my child's view being added to parent's view.

Now, I know there are `beginAppearanceTransition:animated:` and `endAppearanceTransition` methods, added in iOS 6, but I'd like to support iOS 5. It also seems like they are meant to be used in advanced cases:

> Once you add a child to a container, the container automatically
>   forwards rotation and appearance callbacks to the child view
>   controllers as soon as an event occurs that requires the message to be
>   forwarded. This is normally the behavior you want, because it ensures
>   that all events are properly sent. However, sometimes the default
>   behavior may send those events in an order that doesn’t make sense for
>   your container. For example, if multiple children are simultaneously
>   changing their view state, you may want to consolidate the changes so
>   that the appearance callbacks all happen at the same time in a more
>   logical order. To do this, you modify your container class to take
>   over responsibility for appearance or rotation callbacks.

There's also `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method which calls appearance methods at appropriate times, but it requires two view controllers in action and generally looks out of place here. Of course, I may do the trick and feed it a dummy child, but seriously...

Is there anything I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is kinda amusing.

The docs may say that `beginAppearanceTransition:animated:` and `endAppearanceTransition` are available in iOS 6+, but that's not true. These methods are just fine to use in iOS 5 as well:

```
- (void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
- (void)endAppearanceTransition __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16280210/971055) also states the same thing. Case solved!